# How do I run the following query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to table A and B.
The relationship is one to many.
In table B have foreign key from A.

```
TABLE A:
   ... fields

TABLE B:
   f = foreignkey(A)
```

How to get all A without B ?

The query below is not working.

```
select TABLE_A.id, COUNT(TABLE_B.f)  
from TABLE_A JOIN TABLE_B 
   ON (TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.f) 
GROUP BY TABLE_A.id HAVING COUNT(TABLE_B.f) = 0;
```

Comment: answer is
select TABLE_A.id, COUNT(TABLE_B.f)  from TABLE_A LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON (TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.f) GROUP BY TABLE_A.id HAVING COUNT(TABLE_B.f) = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` :

```
TABLE_A.id, COUNT(TABLE_B.f) 
from TABLE_A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON (TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.f) 
GROUP BY TABLE_A.id 
HAVING COUNT(TABLE_B.f) = 0;
```

Comment: With that left join, you should not need to count anything.

Comment: @HaakonDahl please write query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`?

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_b b
                  where a.id = b.f
                 );
```

Or `not in`.  Or `left join` with `where`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` and take only the rows that have `NULL` in the column `TABLE_B.f`, 
meaning that there is no `TABLE_B.f` to match `TABLE_A.id`:

```
SELECT TABLE_A.id  
FROM TABLE_A LEFT JOIN TABLE_B 
ON TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.f 
WHERE TABLE_B.f IS NULL;
```

assuming that `TABLE_A.id` is unique in `TABLE_A`, 
otherwise use

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_A.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the left join and check the nullity on right table.

```
SELECT TABLE_A.id,count(*)  
FROM TABLE_A LEFT JOIN TABLE_B 
ON TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.f 
WHERE TABLE_B.f IS NULL
group by TABLE_A.id;
```